# What is the generator of the group of the units in the field $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

I have shown that $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^3+2x+2)$ is a field. Then the question asks what is the generator of the group of the units? no idea how to proceed from there....

Comment: Well, the group of units has order $27-1 = 26$, so the only possible multiplicative orders an element can have are $1, 2, 13$ and $26$. For any $\alpha$ in your group of units, if you compute $\alpha^{2}, \alpha^{13}$ and neither is $1$, then you've found a generator. A good place to start might be $\alpha = \overline{x}$, the image of $x$ in the quotient...

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I'm wondering how to derive the 27 in the first place?

Comment: Hmm, well, the generality of the answer to that depends on your background. In this case, one can just count here: your field is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$, with basis vectors $\overline{x^{2}}, \overline{x}, \overline{1}$. Therefore, the total number of elements is given by $3^{3} = 27$.

Comment: Why do the basis vectors have degree less than 3? (this given ideal $(x^3+2x+2)$ has degree 3 over $\mathbb{F}_3$...)

Comment: Precisely: since $x^{3}+2x+2$ has degree $3$, $\overline{x}^{3} = \overline{x}+\overline{1}$ in the quotient, so any higher degree power of $\overline{x}$ can be written as a linear combination of powers of $\overline{x}$ of degree $2$ or less.

Comment: Could you explain a little more?... I don't quite understand

Comment: Here is a rough sketch of the algorithm, using an example. I will omit the bars, but I am working in the quotient. In the quotient, $x^3+2x+2 = 0$, so $x^{3} = -2x-2 = x+1$. Say you want to rewrite $x^5$ as a linear combination of $1, x, x^2$. You can write $x^5 = x^{2}(x^{3}) = x^{2}(x+1) = x^{3} + x^{2} = x^{2}+x+1$. Does this make sense? (Implicitly, what you are using is the fact that $\mathbb{F}_{3}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, so you can divide any $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{3}[x]$ by $x^{3}+2x+2$ and get remainder $r(x)$ with degree $< 3$. Then the image of $f(x)$ in the quotient is $r(x)$.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. I think I understand it better now!

Comment: Great, glad I could help! As an aside: $\overline{x}$ is an element of order 13 (though it is a good exercise using the above algorithm to see this!), so you'll want to try a different element. But this strategy should help find an element with *relatively* few computations. :)

Comment: I tried $x$ and it indeed has order 13, but still didn't find an element with order 26...

Comment: Oh should it be $-x$?

Comment: $-x$ should work, since $(-x)^{13} = (-1)^{13}(x)^{13} = -1$! :)

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks a lot!